# How does the luggage car's driver at the airport know what to do?

Tags: airport-operations

I would like to learn a little bit more about the work of luggage car's drivers.

Specifically -- how do any of them know:

- which luggage car to ride next?
- which plane must they deliver this particular luggage car to?
- which roads must they take in order to avoid dangerous situations (crash with an airplane or other airport support cars)?

If this is not a good place for asking questions like that, is there any procedure or source of information which could help me to answer these questions?

Comment: Depends on the airport. But you could also ask how any truck driver anywhere in the world knows where to go, the answer would be similar. Normal procedures for logistics don't disappear just because you are at an airport.

Comment: Well... no. I don't think so. I don't think that normal driver has to take care about 20-50 times bigger vehicles that may appear in their way, while at an airport you must be aware of possible colliding with an airplane when you're riding a luggage car. Plus: normal drivers use road signs and traffic lights that you don't see at parking positions and taxi ways at an airport. Do we have any source of information for such extra procedures, including luggage driver's roosters and "how to go around the airport"?

Comment: Normal traffic laws also apply at airports! Speed limits, right of way etc. There are road signs, and in some cases traffic lights. There are service roads for vehicles to use, which are marked just lige regular roads. Roads are named, just like normal roads, and there are street addresses/numbers. In addition, vehicles must always yield to aircraft, and yield signs are usually posted in places where service roads cross taxiways.

Comment: OK, I see your point. Thanks. But that still makes us talking about last point only. What about two others. Is there any common procedure, same pattern or is this always purely per-airport?

Comment: I think you are overthinking this. The airport has a schedule of all the flights. The handling agency has a bunch of baggage handlers. Their manager tells them what to do. The exact details obviously vary from company to company, airport to airport. In the end, it's just a matter of moving goods from point A to point B. No different from any large warehouse, port or shipping company.

Comment: Sure thing, thanks. So the next point as, as previously -- whether you find it worth to bring these comments into an answer?

Comment: How does a bus or taxi driver know what to do?  How do they know to avoid crashing into things?  How does the ticket agent know what to do?  How do you know how to do your job?  Were you trained?  Probably...

Comment: @trejder: Truck drivers may not have to look out for bigger vehicles - barring the occasional train, of course - but they have to look out for lots and lots of small vehicles.  And pedestrians, critters crossing the road, &c.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. This question was aiming more like into: is there any description available out there about how a typical baggage carrier rooster works like, how his tasks are dispatched etc. It seems from all your comments that this is purely per airport. And that's the answer I was expecting. Thank you.